# How can I temporarily disable events in a WPF solution?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, loaddata

I'm working on a C# WPF solution, based on XAML windows.
On one of those windows, I've added a `DatePicker`, and I want something to be done at two moments:

- When the window is loaded
- When the date in the `DatePicker` is changed.

This can be done very easily:

```
public void LoadData()
{
    date_DatePicker.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today;

    Do_Something();
}
private void DatePicker_DateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (date_DatePicker.SelectedDate.HasValue)
    {
        Do_Something();
    }
}
```

... but you see the problem: as the loading of the window caused a date, being filled in in the `DatePicker`, this launches the `Do_Something()`, causing this method to be launched twice.

I thought of disabling this, by checking `e.OriginalSource`, but apparently the date is already filled in there too (I was hoping `(DatePicker)(e.OriginalSource).SelectedDate` to be `null`).

Is there a way to say something like:

```
public void LoadData()
{
    disable_Events();
    date_DatePicker.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today;
    re-enable_Events();

    Do_Something();
}
```

or:

```
private void DatePicker_DateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((date_DatePicker.SelectedDate.HasValue) && 
        !(previous_value_was_empty(sender,e)))  // <--- does such a thing exist?
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are unnecessarily calling the Do_Something method in the LoadData method. Perhaps in reality, your implementation is different and a double call is really needed there. And here you just oversimplified the code example.

Comment: @EldHasp: nono: I do need the method to be launched at startup and when the `DatePicker` value changes. I have indeed simplified the source code but I did not oversimplify it.

Comment: In your implementation after "date_DatePicker.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today;" the "DatePicker_DateChanged" method will already be called, in which "Do_Something" is called. Why would you call it again in the "LoadData" method itself?

Comment: @EldHasp: oops, now I understand your point! I had first put the `Do_Something()` both in the `LoadData()` and in the event handler. Then I saw that the date was not filled in in the `DatePicker`, so I decided to fill in the date during `LoadData()`, causing the issue I've described. But you are so right: by only launching `Do_Something()` in the event handler, my problem is solved too.

Answer (score 1):

My typical approach is to use a flag:

```
if(!isDoingSomething){
    isDoingSomething = true;
    DoSomething();
    isDoingSomething = false;
}
```

You may want to use try/finally if there is a risk that `DoSomething` throws exceptions.

Comment: I've introduced an `isLoaded` property, doing more or less the same thing. But although it works and gets the job done (hence the upvote), I find it an ugly solution (my question is also about learning more about event handling in WPF).

Comment: @Dominique There is no straightforward "disable events" function in wpf. Even if you find some workaround (copy event list and reset it?), chances are that it will be *more* complicated. But it is difficult to tell what solution will be best without knowing more about the context.

Comment: I was hoping that either `sender` or `e` contained some information about the previous value (as indicated in the edit of my question). I can imagine lots of use cases for such a situation. Also, disabling and enabling events can be very handy (see the `Application.EnableEvents = False` from VBA).

Answer (score 0):

you may try this

````
```cs
private bool isEventEnabled = true;

private void SomeEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       if (isEventEnabled)
{
    // the event handler logic 
}
}

// To temporarily disable events
private void DisableEvents()
{
   isEventEnabled = false;
}

// To re-enable 
private void EnableEvents()
{
    isEventEnabled = true;
}
````

Answer (score 0):

I've found another answer to my question: as mentioned, the loading of the window fills in the `DatePicker`, and I want the `Do_Something()` when the window is loaded **and** when the `DatePicker`'s value is *modified*, but **not** when it simply gets *filled in* while loading the window.

This can be done by checking on `e.RemovedItems.Count`: when the `DatePicker` gets filled in, this value is zero (as nothing is being removed), but while changing the `DatePicker`'s value, the value of `e.RemovedItems.Count` becomes one, so my code becomes:

```
private void DatePicker_DateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((date_DatePicker.SelectedDate.HasValue) && 
        (e.RemovedItems != null) && // I don't know if this even can be null
        (e.RemovedItems.Count != 0))
    {
        Do_Something();
        ...
```